# Изображение в сайте

Tags: html, css

У меня раньше было

```
background:url(../images/bg_body.gif) top left repeat-x #afafaf;
```

Потом bg_body.gif поменял на clouds.jpg. Потом заменил тот фото и обновил страницу опять та фотка потом удалил эту фотку из компютера все так и продолжает отображать ту clouds.jpg помогите?

Comment: Почистите кэш браузера

Comment: а именно как сделать?

Comment: Попробовали бы уже загуглить чтоли... Браузер какой?

Comment: Спасибо  за ответ попытаюсь загуглить

Comment: нет опять отображает ту фотографию я переименовал на clouds1.jpg когда пишу clouds1.jpg вместо clouds.jpg в коде вообще картинка не отображается

Comment: @SportsTubers А если убрать `background`?

Comment: никак  не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
background: url(img/bg.png) center no-repeat;
```

Плюс удостоверьтесь, что на самом деле сохранили изменения в коде

Comment: На самом деле ваш код сработал! спасибо вам